# A question on downloading file via HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

So here's the deal:

I am accessing some webpage(using HtmlUnit) on which there's a button. I programatically click that button,

When I click that button normally through the browser, I am given the chance to save a file on my hard drive.
The thing is, I want to be able to get that file programatically. and save it to a specific folder, if the file size is bigger than a specific number, the downloading should be stopped, Can this be done via HtmlUnit?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... no, this cannot be done.

There is a [firefox/profile base way](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/fa503943b29c0123?pli=1) to partially do that.

And the workaround with `getPageSource()` for plain text files.

Otherwise... I'm looking for similar thing. Let you know if you find a better hack...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file I wanted to download was a text file and below is the code I used. Hope so it gives you an idea about what is to be done.

```
InputStream inputStream = new HttpWebConnection(client).getResponse(req).getContentAsStream();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF8");
        String theString = writer.toString();

        System.out.println(theString);
```